# HTML 5 showing invalid markup

Tags: html

In section `class="container"` shows invalid markup in dreamweaver. Even I don't know what's going wrong even I have done every tag closed and right.

bfcnStore

```
</head>

<body>
    <section class="container">
        <header>
            <figure>

                    <img src="Images/images/header_final.png"/>

            </figure>
        </header>

        <section>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Futsal</a></li>
                    <li><a href="membership.html">Membership</a></li>
                    <li><a href="bfcnStore.html">Store</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contactUs.html">Contact Us</a></li>

                </ul>
            </nav>
        </section>
        </section>


        <section id="contactBfcn">
            <h1>manish shrestha</h1>
        </section>


    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: c'mon seth! hook me up with that correct answer!

Answer (score 1):

you've closed too many section's.  delete one of the /section

and yes, you can delete any one of those 4 closing tags and your markup will be valid. deleting either of the first two will close .container after #contactBfcn and deleting either of the last 2 will close it before. Jason's comment below is incorrect

Comment: This is technically right, but incomplete.  You can't just delete your choice of end tag, there is only one pair of duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

```
</head>
<body>
    <section class="container">
        <header>
            <figure>
                    <img src="Images/images/header_final.png"/>
            </figure>
        </header>
        <section>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Futsal</a></li>
                    <li><a href="membership.html">Membership</a></li>
                    <li><a href="bfcnStore.html">Store</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contactUs.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </section>
        </section>    <------------------ this is whats wrong, a closing tag without opening tag
        <section id="contactBfcn">
            <h1>manish shrestha</h1>
        </section>
    </section>
</body>
```